# Server 2008 GPO To Remove 'Administrative Tools'

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

Is there a way to remove the 'Administrative Tools' link from the Start Menu of a Windows Server 2008 R2 (SBS 2011) using *Group Policy*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your GPO using Group Policy Management Editor, in User Configuration, Control Panel Settings, Start Menu, define a New Start Menu for Windows Vista and later, System administrative tools, Don't display this item.